Getting error while importing incremental data using neo4j admin import tool
Data got successfully loaded into neo4j in full mode. While importing data in incremental mode getting error details of which is mentioned below :
neo4j desktop version:5.19.0
command used for ingesting incremental data:
bin/neo4j-admin database import incremental --stage=prepare --verbose --force --skip-bad-relationships --skip-duplicate-nodes --nodes=import/person_test_incr.csv --nodes=import/touchpoint_incr_test.csv --relationships=import/relationships_incr_test.csv --relationships=import/relationships1_incr_test.csv

Error after executing command:
Neo4j version: 5.19.0
Importing the contents of these files into /home/vboxuser/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-b739dc1f-d763-4964-aca1-7ce12302d613/data/databases/neo4j:
Import mode: prepare
Nodes:
/home/vboxuser/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-b739dc1f-d763-4964-aca1-7ce12302d613/import/person_test_incr.csv
/home/vboxuser/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-b739dc1f-d763-4964-aca1-7ce12302d613/import/touchpoint_incr_test.csv

Relationships:
/home/vboxuser/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-b739dc1f-d763-4964-aca1-7ce12302d613/import/relationships_incr_test.csv
/home/vboxuser/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-b739dc1f-d763-4964-aca1-7ce12302d613/import/relationships1_incr_test.csv

Available resources:
Total machine memory: 7.464GiB
Free machine memory: 570.2MiB
Max heap memory : 910.5MiB
Max worker threads: 2
Configured max memory: 319.9MiB
High parallel IO: true

WARNING Import failed. The store files in /home/vboxuser/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss
/dbms-b739dc1f-d763-4964-aca1-7ce12302d613/data/databases/neo4j are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state. Starting a database on these store files will likely fail or observe inconsistent records so start at your own risk or delete the store manually.

org.neo4j.cli.CommandFailedException: Error importing csv file.
at org.neo4j.importer.ImportCommand$Base.doExecute(ImportCommand.java:464)
at org.neo4j.importer.ImportCommand$Incremental.execute(ImportCommand.java:645)
at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:94)
at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:82)
Caused by: org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter$CsvImportException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find a matching index for (:person {personId})
at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.andPrintError(CsvImporter.java:339)
at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:264)
at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:183)
at org.neo4j.importer.ImportCommand$Base.doExecute(ImportCommand.java:454)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find a matching index for (:person {personId})
at org.neo4j.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:210)
at com.neo4j.internal.batchimport.ParallelIncrementalBatchImporter.findLikelyIndex(ParallelIncrementalBatchImporter.java:2829)
at com.neo4j.internal.batchimport.ParallelIncrementalBatchImporter.copyIndexFilesFromTargetDatabase(ParallelIncrementalBatchImporter.java:2756)
at com.neo4j.internal.batchimport.ParallelIncrementalBatchImporter.prepare(ParallelIncrementalBatchImporter.java:362)
at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:230)
... 15 more 

Csv file structures used for incremental load:
person_test_incr.csv:
personId:ID(person){label:person},email,phone,:LABEL
110001,abc@email110001,9999110001,person
110002,abc@email110002,9999110002,person
110003,abc@email110003,9999110003,person
110004,abc@email110004,9999110004,person
110005,abc@email110005,9999110005,person

touchpoint_incr_test.csv:
touchpointId:ID(touchpoint){label:touchpoint},product,:LABEL
t110001,prd110001,touchpoint
t110002,prd110002,touchpoint
t110003,prd110003,touchpoint
t110004,prd110004,touchpoint
t110005,prd110005,touchpoint

relationships_incr_test.csv:
:START_ID(person),:END_ID(person),email_similarity,phone_similarity,:TYPE
110001,110015,87.8,99,matched
110002,110016,89.9,93.2,matched
110003,110017,98.1,89.8,matched
110004,110018,99,95,matched
110005,110019,81.8,85.9,matched

relationships1_incr_test.csv:
:START_ID(person),:END_ID(touchpoint),:TYPE
110001,t110001,bought
110002,t110002,bought
110003,t110003,bought
110004,t110004,bought
110005,t110005,bought

Tried creating index on personid and touchpointid after base load. Still getting same error. Used same structure files while ingesting base data.Please let me know whether the csv file structure used is of correct format. Also, if I need to change the command that  I am using to ingest data.

I have the same issue

You said that you created "indexes" after the full import, but it is documented that in order to do an incremental import you must actually create node property uniqueness constraints (note: doing so also creates the corresponding indexes automatically).
So, DROP your existing indexes for personId and touchpointId, and create uniqueness constraints instead:
CREATE CONSTRAINT person_personId FOR (p:person) REQUIRE p.personId IS UNIQUE;

CREATE CONSTRAINT touchpoint_touchpointId FOR (t:touchpoint) REQUIRE t.touchpointId IS UNIQUE;

Make sure to exactly specify the label and property names in the above clauses, as they are case sensitive.

If this answer works for you, please also Accept it so that others will know there is a good answer.

i'm not the original author of the question
